# Неверная кодировка при парсинге xml, node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, xmlparser, rss

Есть код:

```
var feedparser = require('ortoo-feedparser');

var url = "http://timeua.com/rss.xml";
feedparser.parseUrl(url).on('article', function(article){
    console.log(article.title);
});
```

использую node.js, результат - выводиться неверная кодировка. Пытаюсь распарсить rss ленту с кириллицей, с анг. текстом все нормально. Подскажите как возможно решить данную проблему?

Comment: Сначала перекодировать в UTF-8, потом парсить.

Comment: я бы просто взял другой парсер